# Is there a non-constant real valued function in $D$ which is analytic in $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there exists a non-constant real valued function in $D$ which is analytic in $D$?

Comment: What is $D$? The disk? Some region? Other?

Comment: $D$ is a region in $\mathbb C$.@AdamHughes

Comment: Then the open mapping theorem doesn't allow this.

Comment: so???@AdamHughes

Answer (score 5):

No. For instance, from Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: So u mean that every analytic real valued function in a region is constant. right??????@orangeskid

Comment: @David: Yep $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a theorem that says that if $\mathbb{D}$ is a region of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is holomorphic in this region, then they're equivalent:

1. The real part of $f$ is constant
2. The imaginary part of $f$ is constant
3. $f$ is constant
4. $\overline{f}$ is holomorphic
5. $|f|$ is constant

So as you can see if $f$ is a non-constant real valued function then it can't be holomorphic.